# Extract int from char* containing special character in Ubuntu gcc

Tags: c++, extract

I have a `char* buf[]` which when printed looks like `(-1.20112344x-2.13413423):2`. I need to extract the two `int`s inside this `char* buf[]` which are inside the `()` and separated by the special character `x`. The `int` may be positive or negative (what I gave as an example is a specific case).

I am compiling using GCC on Ubuntu. Please show me how to do so considering how I am compiling.

Comment: The numbers you show are not `int`, they are `float` (or `double`). Could you rephrase your question? What would you like to get, really? "I want the variable `a` to have the value `1.20112344` and the variable `b` to have a value of `2.13413423`" or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, the following program should help (edited following the comment by paxdiablo - using `double` rather than `float` type, and returning the result to 8 significant figures).

```
include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  char* s=" (-1.20112344x-2.13413423):2 ";
  double a, b;
  sscanf(s, " (%lfx%lf", &a, &b);
  printf("a is %.8lf; b is %.8lf\n", a, b);
}
```

When run, this returns

```
a is -1.20112344; b is -2.13413423
```

The `sscanf` function scans a string for numbers following the format given - in this case, the format string `" (%lfx%lf"` says: "skip a space-open-bracket `(`, then read a double `%lf`, putting the result in the location pointed to by the address of a: `&a` (i.e. put the result in `a`). Skip the `x`, then find another double and store the result in `b`.

Comment: I'd probably prefer to see doubles rather than floats but the idea is sound. My original thought was to use a `strchr/strtod` combo but this answer is much better.

Comment: @paxdiablo - the OP started asking about `int`... so I really didn't know where I needed to go. Agree that a `double` might be a better type in general to represent a number with 9 significant figures; it all depends on what you want to do with it, really.